# Docker not importing Python file

Tags: python, docker, import

I am building a python file that gives you the ETH balance from any crypto wallet. I want to do this by running the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.6

ADD main.py .

RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

main.py imports WalletData.py (containing web3 requests). This works just fine when I run main.py manualy but when I try to do it using the Dockerfile I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WalletData'". What can I do?

[The workspace has the following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cno4s.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to **add** or **copy** your */app* folder to container. Only main.py is added to container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add all your files in docker container using COPY / ADD command, in case WalletData is custom module. You can also use pip install if you are using any third party modules/libraries

eg for adding custom module to Docker Container using Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.6

ADD /app .
ADD main.py .
ADD requirement.txt .


RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't get this error anymore. It was this simple. Now I can work on errors elsewhere in the code :)